# Ubuntu published OS patch/package

Tags: 10.04

I am very new to this community and Ubuntu OS.  I am currently on a project to create a mirror repository server.  However our patching policy is very restricted.  Before we add patch to the mirror server, we need to know details of the fix and we only allow to update specific patch. That way we only upgrade what we know and what we actually need to the client servers. Please help me with questions below:

1. where all OS published patch/package are posted?
2. how do I control apt-mirror to update specific patch/package?

Answer (score 1):

I don't mean to sound rude, but if you're so new to Ubuntu, why do you think you're better qualified than Ubuntu developers to decide which update is worth it? Updates for release Ubuntu versions only include bugfixes and security fixes, you'll generally want all of those.

If you wish to inspect changelogs, they can be found on pages like https://launchpad.net/ubuntu/quantal/+source/python-keystoneclient/ for every source package.

Comment: I do agree that developers who know their software and their patches are the ones who should decide what patches are useful.

Comment: Thanks for your quick response.  We would like to have control internally since all fixes/patches have to go through QA team before arriving to the mirror server.  Most importantly we would like to obtain fix only address exactly our need.  For example I found an issue on tomcat6 package. We can look up on publish website for fix details, then update only tomcat6 to the mirror server.  We believe that way we could have more stable environment.

Comment: ...and run the risk of running into (security) bugs later because you don't update all packages :)

Comment: sercurity patch will be QA'ed before going to mirror server ;-)

Comment: we have our own QA process because we would like to assure new OS patch would not break our application in our own environment which Ubuntu team may not have verified the patch from.